# How to interface ultrasonic with raspberry pi through IOPI plus AB Electronics UK

Tags: raspbian

```py
import time

try:
    from IOPi import IOPi
except ImportError:
    print("Failed to import IOPi from python system path")
    print("Importing from parent folder instead")
    try:
        import sys
        sys.path.append("..")
        from IOPi import IOPi
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(
            "Failed to import library from parent folder")


def main():
    """
    Main program function
    """

    # create two instances of the IoPi class called iobus1 and iobus2 and set
    # the default i2c addresses
#     iobus1 = IOPi(0x20)  # bus 1 will be inputs
    iobus2 = IOPi(0x21)  # bus 2 will be outputs

    # Each bus is divided up two 8 bit ports.  Port 0 controls pins 1 to 8,
    # Port 1 controls pins 9 to 16.
    # We will read the inputs on pin 1 of bus 1 so set port 0 to be inputs and
    # enable the internal pull-up resistors
#     iobus1.set_port_direction(0, 0xFF)
#     iobus1.set_port_pullups(0, 0xFF)

    # We will write to the output pin 1 on bus 2 so set port 0 to be outputs
    # and turn off the pins on port 0
    iobus2.set_port_direction(0, 0x00)
    iobus2.write_port(0, 0x00)

    while True:

        # read pin 1 on bus 1.  If pin 1 is high set the output on
        # bus 2 pin 1 to high, otherwise set it to low.
        # connect pin 1 on bus 1 to ground to see the output on
        # bus 2 pin 1 change state.

         if
            iobus2.write_pin(1, 1)
        else:
            iobus2.write_pin(1, 0)

        # wait 0.1 seconds before reading the pins again
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just posting a code snippet will not help much to understand your problem. Can you please elaborate your question? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.